# Complex equation $\log(z^2)=2\log(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need help solving the following equation for complex:

$$\log(z^2)=2\log(z)$$

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Is that supposed to be $2*\log(z)$? If so, it is one of the identities of logarithms.

Comment: I am trying to open the complex logarithm and i'm getting nothing with this

Comment: This property, as others in logarithms and also exponents *in the complex numbers* are false... **unless** you choose a definite branch of the logarithm, and even then, without further condition, it remains false in general.

Comment: what about fixing a domain ?? complex plan less the negative real axis and zero ??

Comment: @AlgorithmsX : Your comment presupposes that the logarithm is well defined when $z$ is complex.  And could you write $2\log z$ or $2\cdot\log z$ or $2\times\log z$?  Using an asterisk for that is vulgar: It's a workaround for occasions when one is limited to the characters on the keyboard. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Good points. I just wanted some clarification on what he was trying to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we write $\;z=|z|e^{it}\;\implies\;z^2=|z|^2e^{2it}\;$ , then by definition

$$\text{Log}\, z=\log|z|+it\;,\;\;\text{Log}\,z^2=\log|z|^2+i2t=2\log|z|+2it$$

Yet, if the branch chosen in the "usual" one $\;(-\infty,0]\;$ and, for example, we choose $\;z=i\;$ , then $\;z^2=-1\;$ , and then

$$\text{Log}\,i=\log|i|+\frac{\pi i}2=\frac{\pi i}2\;,\;\;\text{Log}\,i^2=\text{Log}\,(-1)=\log|-1|-\pi i=-\pi i$$

and we don't get equality. Now, if possible and always trying to take $\;-\pi<\arg z\le\pi\;$ , we can make things work out *if we work with the argument in modulo*, meaning that we "make the argument" jump into the strip we want it to remain. This looks like cheating...and it is cheating: if you've heard of Riemann surfaces, is like "sliding" down (or up) from one sheet to another.

It's not a coincidence that the complex logarithm function isn't really dealt with in many introductory classes of complex analysis: it can be a pain in...there to understand all the fine details.

Comment: *pain in... there* I like your descriptions.